# VBA Numberformat differently for each range

Tags: vba, excel, decimal, number-formatting

I want to change the format of my ranges according to the number of decimals from the second cell. Any idea? 
I am using the following Function to count Decimals (works)

```
Function CountDecimalPlaces(aNumber As Double) As Long

Dim len1 As Long, len2 As Long
len1 = Len(CStr(aNumber))
len2 = Len(CStr(Int(aNumber)))
CountDecimalPlaces = len1 - len2 + CLng(len1 <> len2)

End Function
```

and would like to use this to format my range with different amount of decimals

```
For b = 1 To lastCol

Range(cells(3,b),cells(50,b)).NumberFormat = "0." & CountDecimalPlaces (Cells(2, b)) x 0

Next b
```

Of course I know the "CountDecimalPlaces (Cells(2, b)) x 0" doesn t work but I hope it make it understandable for you to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
Range(cells(3,b),cells(50,b)).NumberFormat = "0." & String(CountDecimalPlaces(Cells(2, b)), "0")
```

The `String` takes two mandatory arguments:

- `Number`: The number of times a character has to be repeated
- `Character`: The character that has to be repeated

Here's another way you can count the number of decimals in a number:

```
Function CountDecimalPlaces(aNumber As Double) As Long
    CountDecimalPlaces = Len(Split(CStr(aNumber), ".")(1))
End Function
```

**Edit** (based on Excelosaurus' suggestions):

```
Function CountDecimalPlaces(aNumber As Double) As Long
    If Int(aNumber) = aNumber Then
        CountDecimalPlaces = 0
    Else
        CountDecimalPlaces = Len(Split(CStr(aNumber), Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator))(1))
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: The proposed function will fail for whole numbers and on systems using anything else than a period as a decimal separator. Use Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator).

Comment: @Excelosaurus, thanks for pointing that out. I've modified the function I posted.

Comment: It now returns either 0 or 1 due to the imposed format. Don't think you'll cram this into a clean one-liner :-) I'd go with If Round(aNumber, 0) = aNumber Then CountDecimalPlaces = 0 Else CountDecimalPlaces= Len(Split(CStr(aNumber), Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator), Compare:=vbBinaryCompare)(1))) End If.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your counting decimal as below as well.

```
 Function CountDecimalPlaces(aNumber As Double) As String

 Dim len1 As Long, len2, lenX As Long
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim answer As String
 answer = "0."
 len1 = Len(CStr(aNumber))
 len2 = Len(CStr(Int(aNumber)))
 lenX = len1 - len2 + CLng(len1 <> len2)
 If lenX > 0 Then
     For i = 1 To lenX
         answer = answer & "0"
     Next i     
 End If
 CountDecimalPlaces = answer
 End Function
```

and use in your main function like this :

```
 Range(cells(3,b),cells(50,b)).NumberFormat = CountDecimalPlaces (Cells(2, b))
```